# Escaping jinja template for javascript place holder

Tags: javascript, templates, web-applications, jinja2

I want to pass a javascript variable `${channels[i]}` to my `jinja2` template as a  placeholder for the `href` attribute of the link tag.

I have tried `{% raw %}{% endraw %}` [tags](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#html-escaping) to escape `&quot;` html entity but it seems that the `jinja2` throws an exception as `%` is an unidentified character.

Have a look at my code below:

```js
for(i=0; i<=channels.length-1; i++) {
  console.log(channels[i])
  const li = document.createElement("li");

  li.innerHTML = `<a href="{{ url_for('channel', channel_name = ${channels[i]}) }}" >${channels[i]}</a>`;

  ul.append(li);
}
```

any help or any other method to accomplish the task would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing things, you can't evaluate javascript variables in `jinja2` expression `{{ .. }}`.

`jinja2` renders your template on the **server-side** and the HTML output is served to the **client-side** (the browser), whereas the javascipt (your code) manipulates the `DOM` of the received HTML on the **client-side** (the browser). so how they would talk to each other ?
you have 3 options:

- using `ajax` to perform http requests (not your case)
- reviewing the code and moving the logic to `jinja2` (strongly recommended)
- or trying this hack:

```
[..]

  let href = "{{ url_for('channel', channel_name='CHANNEL_NAME'} }}".replace("CHANNEL_NAME", ${channels[i])
  li.innerHTML = "<a href=" + href + ">${channels[i]}</a>";

[..]
```

bear in mind that `jinja2` will render your template and serve this output:

```
for(i=0; i<= channels.length-1; i++) {
  console.log(channels[i])
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  
  let href = "http://localhost:5000/channel/CHANNEL_NAME".replace("CHANNEL_NAME", ${channels[i])
  li.innerHTML = "<a href=" + href + ">${channels[i]}</a>";
  
  ul.append(li);
};
```

and once received by the client, the javascript code can be executed and then process the replacement of the `CHANNEL_NAME` token with the value of `${channels[i]}`