# Shows an output as Undefined in jquery val () attribute in flask template

Tags: python, jquery, flask

The below code shows an output as Undefined... but the value is displayed in alert box

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-homeEvents", function () {
  var eventId = $(this).data('id');
  alert(eventId); // It returns value as (1,2,3,...)
  $("input[name='bname']").val("{{business_field_data[" + eventId + "].business_name}}"); // Error eventId Undefined
 });
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: #1 in javascript avoid `alert()` and prefer `console.log()` #2 code code javascript looks correct #3 you can't mix javacsript and `jinj2` expression see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109695/escaping-jinja-template-for-javascript-place-holder/62622741#62622741

Comment: Thanks @cizario... but its not work for me... actually i am getting eventid from data-id attribute... and display it in form input tag using jquery..i think the issue is due to "the scope of variable is not working after alert or the variable declaration syntax is incorrect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(".open-homeEvents").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var eventId = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(eventId);
    
    // problem: see below 
    $("input[name='bname']").val("{{ business_field_data[" + eventId + "].business_name}} ");

   ...

  });

})
```

you are mixing things, you can't evaluate javascript variables in `jinja2` expression `{{ .. }}`.

`jinja2` renders your template on the **server-side** and the HTML output is served to the **client-side** (the browser), whereas the javascipt (your code) manipulates the `DOM` of the received HTML on the **client-side** (the browser).

Comment: Thanks... I used the above code but it displays an arror as        
                                                                                    
                jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute ' + eventId + '

Comment: i already explained that ! you can't inject javascript variable in jinja expression , you need to review the logic of your code