# Jinja templating not working in script.js

Tags: flask, jinja2

I need to include jinja templating in element.innerHTML but jinja is not working.

Code script.js:

```
contentDiv.innerHTML = getContent(fragmentId);

function getContent(fragmentId) {
var pages = {

    quad1: `
            <form class="form-inline" method="POST" id="form1">
                <h3>
                    <input type="number" id="quad_a1" name="input_a" class="form-control mx-2 col-1" placeholder="a">
                    <b>x&#178; +</b>
                    <input type="number" id="quad_b1" name="input_b" class="form-control mx-2 col-1" placeholder="b">
                    <b>x +</b>
                    <input type="number" name="input_c" class="form-control mx-2 col-1" placeholder="c">
                    <b>=</b>
                    <input type="number" name="input_d" class="form-control mx-2 col-2" placeholder="Default(0)">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mr-5" onclick="return empty_quad()">Solve</button>
                </h3>
            </form>
            {{ sol }}
            `,
.
.
.
};
return pages[fragmentId];
}
```

But the output is literally {{ sol }}, not the value of sol:
[image]

So how to access the variable sol passed through flask's render_template() in script.js?

Comment: have a look at this, it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622741/12368419

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jinja2 template in your js file.

First method: You have to use inline javascript in html file using `<script></script>` tag, and then you can access the sol variable by assigning it to javascript variable

```
<script> sol = "{{sol}}" </script> // {{sol}} should be between quotation marks
```

Second method: If you have seperate js file. you can make a div tag, define it's class and set it's id to `{{sol}}`. get the element by class name and then get it's id.

Html

`<div class="myclass" id="{{sol}}" style="display:none"></div>`

javascript

```
elem= document.getElementsByClassName("myclass") ;
console.log(elem.id) // this is the sol value.
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returned  HTMLCollection instead element, so you have to write something like this: `console.log(elem[0].id)`

Answer (score 0):

**json_script**

Safely outputs a Python object as JSON, wrapped in a `<script>` tag, ready for use with JavaScript.

Argument: HTML `“id”` of the `<script>` tag.

For example:

```
{{ value|json_script:"hello-data" }}
```

If value is the dictionary `{'hello': 'world'}`, the output will be:

```
<script id="hello-data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world"}</script>
```

The resulting data can be accessed in JavaScript like this:

```
const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
```

XSS attacks are mitigated by escaping the characters `“<”, “>”` and `“&”`. For example if value is `{'hello': 'world</script>&amp;'}`, the output is:

```
<script id="hello-data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world\\u003C/script\\u003E\\u0026amp;"}</script>
```

This is compatible with a strict Content Security Policy that prohibits in-page script execution. It also maintains a clean separation between passive data and executable code.

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)